# Creating Add-In parts with C#?

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, csom

I have a home page on a sharepoint site and want to add a frame with my aspx from my visual studio sharepoint c# add-in and all its functionality. Is that possible? So far I only stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/sp-add-ins/create-add-in-parts-to-install-with-your-sharepoint-add-in.md) but it uses JavaScript. Are there any guidelines on how to do it in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create provider-hosted add-in and create add-in part to target the remote web page, so you could use C# api in remote web page backend.
[image]